Typographical standards: incorporating italicized titles of creative works in other proper nouns
It is standard that creative works have their titles italicized, so: Star Trek, the Harry Potter franchise, Shahnameh, etc. But supposing one of these italicized titles was co-opted by another proper noun. Such as, the "Fort Worth Star Trek Fan Club". Would the typography be entirely normal or should it be "Fort Worth Star Trek Fan Club"?
I've tried Googling for this sort of thing, but it's difficult to come up with search terms that will separate the chaff from the wheat. I also asked Google Gemini, which says that the typeface should be entirely normal in that situation, which it credits the Chicago Manual of Style, but couldn't give me a reference to it.

When one proper noun becomes part of another proper noun, the orthographic rule(s) for the latter apply to its whole.
For example, personal names are represented in roman or regular type:

President-elect Donald J. Trump will inherit a dangerous new Middle East crisis in Syria when he assumes office in January.

But when that personal name becomes part of a book title, the rules for book titles apply and the name is represented in italics, like the rest of the title:

Rob Sears is the author of the hit humour titles The Beautiful Poetry of Donald Trump, Vladimir Putin: Life Coach, Choose Your Own Apocalypse with Kim Jong-Un and Friends and most recently Elon Musk's Billionaire School.

And when a book title, that would be given in italics, becomes part of the name of an organisation, it is given in regular type along with the other words of the organisation name:

Every Wednesday after school, Star Trek fan Donald J. went to the Fort Worth Star Trek Fan Club.

